# How to change a class of the main.css in ionic

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

in my ion datetime i have the problem that in android the am/pm display like this "..." and doesnt show a the letters

I look in the inspector that some div has a

```
class="picker-opts"
```

and a

```
style="max-width:34px"
```

if i manage to change the 34px to 70px, it displays good in the app.

this is how it looks, in other android devices almost all the numbers are in the same dots
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4qV8.jpg

Comment: Try in your `global.scss`: `.picker-opts { max-width: 70px !important; }`

Comment: thanks!, works like a charm, i resolved by doing the same but copying the entire path to the class with their content, but this solution is way better, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ionic3 used app.scss file

```
.picker-opts { 
      max-width: 70px !important; 
 }
```

In ionic4 used global.scss file

```
.picker-opts { 
      max-width: 70px !important; 
 }
```